# Container.ItemIndex doesn't work Inside an attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an ASP repeater control to output a list to the visitor.

I want to have a delete link that will remove the item from the list using a function "Remove" in my codebehind.

To get this to work I need to pass the Container.ItemIndex value as an arguement, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I tried this code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Remove" runat="server" OnCommand="Remove" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

But when I try to insert `Container.ItemIndex` into `CommandArgument` it does not work.

I'm baffled and have hit a dead end. Can anyone see what I am trying to do and help me?

Comment: what is the complete code for your control for inserting the link-button? The Container-variable is only accessible from ItemTemplate or AlternatingItemTemplate.

Comment: and btw, "does not work" is *never* an acceptable thing to say in this context! always write what happened or which error was outputted.

Comment: I am sorry. I closed the project down, opened it up again and now it works.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it wasn't working.

Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe single quotes are required with code blocks:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Remove" runat="server" OnCommand="Remove" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: has nothing to say... you only need single-quotes when the code-expression calls a function that for instance takes a string-parameter where you have to write the method call statement with double-quotes.